# Is there any mnemonic to recall use of have/has, including exceptions?

Tags: grammar, mnemonic

I can't remember where to use "has" and where to use "have". 
If I practice the exceptions and keep them revise few months I can toughly superficially memorize, but I again forgets them.

I'm non-native English-user as well belong autism-spectrum. I feel problems with memorizing discrete, 2-bit informations, for say bus route numbers, friend's birth-dates and institutions. whereas I've no problem with memorizing bigger yet continuous informations like how phloem loading and unloading mechanism works, or of what family a plant could be, or what does integral-calculus actually mean.

Could anyone could provide mnemonics to remember the use of Have and Has with their exceptions?

Comment: *Has* is used only for third person singular subjects - there are no exceptions to worry about!

Comment: Have is 4-letter, so bigger ... plural. Has is 3 letter, small ... singular. However not universal.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused ... Not good enough.  "I have" singular? "He has" singular?

Comment: @GEdgar "He" is singular "They" is plural

Comment: @AlwaysConfused But ‘I’ and ‘you’ are also singular, that's why it doesn't work to just say “singular = has”. It has to be specifically “third person singular = has”.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused: If you think of the words as letters instead of sounds you will remain confused. _have_ and _has_ sound very similar, and differ only at the end - one has a final /v/, the other has a final /z/. In speech, they mostly appear as contractions -- _he's_ and _they've_, for instance, pronounced /hi:z/ and /ðe:v/ -- and aren't pronounced as separate syllables. But I empathize with your perceptual condition; there may be a large-scale analysis available. I'll work on it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks it is an excellent suggestion. I stay confused to determine "I has/have", but easily recall "I've". Also previously thought this way, how native English-speakers (those had not learnt vowels and consonants from grammar books), can naturally remember where to use "an" and where to use "a". It was an enigma for me for many years. Much-much Later-on I thought that probably the "n" of an is being used as a separator for two successive vowels (a and the next vowel); and also this is why "an" is not required before one-eyed-deer, just like "a wallpaper"

Comment: @JohnLawler So you're probably telling to deal the rules-of grammar not to memorize-and-recall like courtroom-rules, but for instantly determine or  'create' them from which-way they are swift to pronounce.

Comment: @Moderators feel free to move this question to English learners' (beginner's) website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that *have* and *has* follow the same pattern as all “he-*verbs*” type inflections. There is no exception to be learned here, and therefore than can be no mnemonic.

All ***third-person singular verbs in the present tense*** (plus also *be* in the preterite) have a distinct /z/ inflection ending in *-s*. “Third-person singular” means whenever the subject is any of he, she, it, your mother, the neighbor, the neighbor’s cat, or the neighborhood itself.

How this is spelled or said varies:

- be: is, was
- have: has
- do: does
- say: says
- go: goes
- get: gets
- make: makes
- take: takes
- see: sees
- find: finds
- give: gives
- need: needs
- try: tries

If the unmarked version of the verb ends in an unvoiced consonant, that /z/ devoices to /s/, but not otherwise.

This /z/ form of the verb is sometimes called the [VBZ](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) form in part-of-speech tag markups.

---

Be careful, though, or the internet will spoof you:

[image: Lolcat: “I can haz cheezeburgerz?”]

That’s deliberately ungrammatical because kitties aren’t good at English.

Comment: You mean HAS=HAVE+S like does, tells etc? lot of helpful

Answer (score -1):

You can ask yourself this question to decide whether it's /has/ or /have/.
[I understand binary confusion, I have it too.]

Has and have are used in contexts.

He has lots of money. She has none. The dog has a bone. The dog has  no bone.

The test: In your sentence (you always need a sentence) is the word HE or SHE used? If yes, the answer is /has/.

If there is no he or she, is there a THING? An it? like; The cake (it) looks good. If yes, then the answer is /has/.

Summary: Ask the question: Does my sentence begin with SHE or HE or IT [thing] or does it contain SHE, HE or IT? If it is yes, HAS. 
If it does not begin or contain SHE or HE or IT [thing], use HAVE.

Mnemonic:
HE, SHE, IT = HAS   [in grammar, third person singular]

Everything else = HAVE [in grammar, all other persons, I, you, we, they!]

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot to quick-understand user@tchrist's answer

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Yes that's exactly how it works.

Comment: Why this answer has been downvoted? nothing wrong I found here. I can't  accecpt more than one answer due to site's structure but every piece of answers and comments are valuable for me.

Comment: @Always Confused  In English, HE, SHE, IT is always with an S in the ***present tense***. has, does, walks, talks, listens, flies (careful irregular), Even the verb /to be/: He ***is***. HE/SHE/IT + S. Another device.